# "uninitialized constant ActiveRecord" error when making new object of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, uninitialized-constant

I'm making a sign-up form for my website using Rails 4.0.0.  In my homepage (called by a controller named 'public'), I have a form for signing up:

in `app/views/public/index.html.erb`

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>                                       
  ...                          
  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>                             
  <% end %>
```

I have the @user object in my `app/controllers/public_controller.rb` file:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController                           
  def index                                                              
    @user = User.new                                                     
  end                                                                    
end
```

However, when I try to load the page, I get an `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord` error, showing that the problem is on line 1 of my `app/models/user.rb` file which says

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

---

The framework trace spat out from the website says:

```
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__533378866__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__904644984__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
faye-websocket (0.7.0) lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:40:in `process'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
faye-websocket (0.7.0) lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:44:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas what's wrong with this?  I figured that it wouldn't be a problem to initialize an object of some arbitrary model, but I'm pretty stumped on this one.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you `create` method on your controller?

Comment: Did you comment out loading ActiveRecord in your `config/application.rb`?

Comment: is this a fresh app? are you migrating it from an old version? do you require rails/all in application.rb?